# Pasting multiline commands

Tags: notebooks, formatting

If i copy and paste something from one nb to another it works normally.

[image]

But if I copy from any other app it just puts everything in the same line.

[image]

Recently, I have automated my workflow in Mathematica with Touch Portal and Razer Naga sinapse 3. I have manny commands as long as this one below.

[image]

Those long commands become very unreadable when put into a single line.

Is there a way to make pasting work normally?

Comment: You can give Code cells a try. You create them with Alt + 8 and they behave more like plain text than Input cells.

Comment: Thanks. With code cells it works perfectly.